# Compare a string date from xml file with today's date and delete the node from the xml if the date has expired. The string date is in format dd/MM/yy

Tags: java, xml, date

```
   public void BrisiOdXML(List<Nastani> lista)
  {
    try {
        //reading from xml

        File fXmlFile = new File("/Users/Darko/workspace/Seminarska_1/nastani.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();


        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Nastan");
```

//today's date
// i can't get today's date in dd/MM/yy format without the time

```
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

//searching the list

```
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);              

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;


//string date from xml dile in format dd/MM/yy  

     Date datexml = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy").parse(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Datum").item(temp).getTextContent());                      
//comparing today's date with date from the xml file

       if (today.after(datexml))
     {

        //removing node

         nNode.getParentNode().removeChild(nNode);


                 doc.normalize();
                 prettyPrint(doc);

     }
            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
```

//printing the new xml file

```
   public static final void prettyPrint(Document xml) throws Exception {

            Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

            tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

            tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

            Writer out = new StringWriter();

            tf.transform(new DOMSource(xml), new StreamResult(out));

            System.out.println(out.toString());
        }

}
```

// it suppose  to delete the node from the xml file if the date has expired, but when i read the xml list it only displays error messages and shows tho whole list

Answer (score 0):

What you are comparing in the method `after` is Calendar vs. Date. I am not sure if that's correct. Try to convert the `datexml` to `Calendar` as well by doing this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(datexml);
```